# Prepended ampersand convering to htmlentities

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a string with a prepended ampersand.

```
$teststring = "My name is &test not & test OK";
```

The string saved to the Db is "My name is &test; not & test OK"

with a semicolon after test only after the first &.
I'm not sure if this is from php, codeigniter, or custom code.
Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks

Comment: Without actually seeing the code processing this string, I don't know how we can help you.  Something is trying to escape this as an html entity and failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the [xss_clean function in CI](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/84137/).  Try using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on your strings first.